# Why do I get the stack smashing error while working with arrays in c?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to solve the 3Sum problem but I don't know why I always get the ''*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated'' error, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int proc(int t[], int n, int* r) {
  int c=0;
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
           for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
               if(i!=j!=k){
                  if(t[i]+t[j]+t[k]==0){
                     r[c]=t[i];
                      c++;
                     r[c]=t[j];
                     c++;
                     r[c]=t[k];
                     c++;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return c;

}
void main(){
    
     int t[6]={-1,0,1,2,-1,-4}, r[6], c;
    
  c=add(t, 6, r);
  
  for(int i=0; i<c; i++)
     printf("%d ", r[i]);


}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but `i!=j!=k` is wrong.

Comment: Is the `add(...)` function call a call to `proc`? It should be `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with your program (as pointed out, `i!=j!=k` will not work as you think for example).

But the reason for stack smashing is that you are incrementing c to the point where it exceeds the size of your arrays then you do r[c]. When you try to access an index that is above the size of the array you get the error.

For example, if you replace your

```
int t[6]={-1,0,1,2,-1,-4}, r[6], c;
```

by

```
int t[6]={-1,0,1,2,-1,-4}, r[1000], c;
```

**(don't actually solve this problem this way)**
you will see that the error no longer occur because c never exceeds the size of the r array...

The solution is to compute the maximum value of c beforehand, or use a different data-structure.

Note: for the 3sum problem, it should be possible to calculate the maximum, but you have many more problems here, and most likely it's expected that r should be a 2 dimensional array anyways. At least in leetcode a two dimensional array is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find problem if you use debugger and run your program step by step.
`i!=j!=k` is not correct, you probably meant `i!=j && j!=k` or `i!=j && j!=k && i!=k`

But most importantly `c` after few loops is greater than 6, so you're out of array bounds

Answer (score 0):

This if statement

```
if(i!=j!=k){
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( ( i != j ) != k ){
```

The expression i != j evaluates either to 1 if i is unequal to j or 0 otherwise.

So you will have either

```
if ( 1 != k ){
```

or

```
if ( 0 != k ){
```

Instead of

```
if(i!=j!=k){
```

you need to write

```
if ( ( i != j ) && ( j != k ) && ( i != k ) ){
```

Another problem is that this code snippet

```
  if(t[i]+t[j]+t[k]==0){
     r[c]=t[i];
      c++;
     r[c]=t[j];
     c++;
     r[c]=t[k];
     c++;
   }
```

can result in writing to memory outside the array pointed to by the pointer `r`.

Also it seems that instead of these for loops

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
```

you mean the following for loops

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
        for(int k=j+1; k<n; k++){
```

And pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```